Is this drive dead?: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
Having bought a used PC and now installing smartd on it, I'm getting smartd "Critical Warning (0x04): Reliability" emails about it (full pastebin). The Percentage Used: 112% is concerning. Is that enough for smartd to declare "Critical Warning (0x04): Reliability"?
This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

   host name:  kosh
   DNS domain: [Empty]

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/nvme0, Critical Warning (0x04): Reliability

Device info:
Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB, S/N:S4EWNM0R328374F, FW:2B2QEXM7, 1.00 TB

<snip>

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)

<snip>
Percentage Used:                    112%
<snip>

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS  Message
  0       4357     0  0x0010  0x4004      -            0     0     -  Invalid Field in Command

Self-test Log (NVMe Log 0x06)
Self-test status: No self-test in progress
No Self-tests Logged

It looks to me like the "Invalid Field in Command" errors are red herrings since I'm running smartmontools version 7.4 where https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/1222 has been fixed, so that should not cause tests to fail.
I then ran:
$ sudo smartctl -t short /dev/nvme0n1

and now sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1 ends with:
Self-test Log (NVMe Log 0x06)
Self-test status: No self-test in progress
Num  Test_Description  Status                       Power_on_Hours  Failing_LBA  NSID Seg SCT Code
 0   Short             Completed: failed segments             3535            -     1   2   -    -
 1   Short             Completed: failed segments             3535            -     1   2   -    -

But I don't know how to get more information about the "failed segments".
Is this enough for me to conclude that the disk is bad and needs replacement, or it there still hope for it?

Critical Warning is a bit field read directly from the device itself. smartmontools then only displays it to you... so you're looking for an interpretation that smartmontools itself doesn't do. Technically smartctl does not display this because of reason X or Y; the drive firmware sets the failure bit internally out of its own considerations.
See NVM Express® Base Specification, Figure 208, Page 200 where this particular critical warning bit is described as such:

Critical Warning: This field indicates critical warnings for the state of the controller. Each bit
corresponds to a critical warning type; multiple bits may be set to ‘1’. If a bit is cleared to ‘0’,
then that critical warning does not apply. Critical warnings may result in an asynchronous
event notification to the host. Bits in this field represent the state at the time the Get Log Page
command is processed and may not reflect the state at the time a related asynchronous event
notification, if any, occurs or occurred.


Bits: 2 | Definition: If set to ‘1’, then the NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded due to significant
media related errors or any internal error that degrades NVM subsystem reliability.

(Bits are counted from 0 here, so Critical Warning (0x04) is bit 2).
Is Percentage Used enough to set this bit? It's possible. I did a Google search for smartctl outputs of Samsung EVO SSDs and those few I could find with Percentage Used >100%, all had it set.
You still shouldn't get failed segments in a self-test though. Perhaps run a long selftest as well as a read-only test using badblocks (don't use -n or -w) or dd?
If in doubt: replace the drive.
